# Media query and if else statement in LESS

Tags: less

In Sass I hadle responsive like this. But how can I write this in LESS. I find the way that they use when but I still cannot write it correctly in LESS

```
html {
  /*font-size: 10px;*/

  font-size: 62.5%; //1 rem = 10px; 10px/16px = 62.5%

  @include respond(tab-land) {
    font-size: 56.25%; //1 rem = 9px; 9px/16px = 56.25%
  }

  @include respond(tab-port) {
    font-size: 50%; //1 rem = 8px; 8px/16px = 50%
  }

  @include respond(big-desktop) {
    font-size: 75%; //1 rem = 12px; 10px/16px = 62.5%
  }
}


@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
  @if $breakpoint == phone {
    @media (max-width: 37.5em) {@content} //600px
  }

  @if $breakpoint == tab-port {
    @media (max-width: 56.25em) {@content}  //900px
  }

  @if $breakpoint == tab-land {
    @media (max-width: 75em) {@content}  //1200px
  }

  @if $breakpoint == big-desktop {
    @media (min-width: 112.5em) {@content}  //1800
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature).
Less mixin:

```
.respond(@size, @content) {
  & when(@size = phone) {
    @media (max-width: 37.5em) { @content() }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
.a {
  .respond(phone, {
    color: red;
  });
  .respond(unknown, {
    color: green;
  });
}
```

Compiles to:

```
@media (max-width: 37.5em) {
  .a {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/MzXMXm?editors=0110).

Comment: It is very strange that when I use max-width: 37.5em, it does not work. But when I use min-width: 0px and max-width: 37.5em then it works. Your code works because you use only one media query (phone)

Comment: I just copy-paste one of yours media queries. This code is just an example of css guards usage. You can write your own media expressions.

Comment: This one does not work https://pastebin.com/yc5gFnNe but this does https://pastebin.com/6T2eZvQk. Strange?

Comment: You write two different blocks of code. Each code block works in its own way. I don'tt understand what is your question.

Comment: where is the 'green' in the compiled code?